# how to type `` in latin american keyboard

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, latin

I can't get it done in my Latin American keyboard .... I need it often in Node.JS ...  while I'm coding. ... specially some strings. .... otherwise it doesn't bring the results. I need using simple quotes: '' ... .I would appreciate any help .. . 
What I do sometimes is to change to a US keyboard and I get the quotes somehow ... 
for example in a code like this I need this kind of quotes:

```
throw new Error(`Expected 44, but got ${res}`)
```

as I said specifically this:

```
`` in Latin American keyboard
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my ("latin american") keyboard I type <kbd>AltGr</kbd> + <kbd>}</kbd>. And [here](http://www.custombit.com.ar/acentos/) you can find an old software that reads the keyboard layout and shows the key or combination for getting it.

Comment: Excellent ! Thanks a lot! it works perfectly .. as you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>dead à</kbd>?
Else, maybe you find your answer here [keyboards layouts](http://kbd-intl.narod.ru/english/layouts)